# wireless adapter TL-WN781ND

Tags: wireless

```
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/core
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/hal
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/include
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/os_dep
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/platform
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/clean
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/ifcfg-wlan0
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/Kconfig
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/Makefile
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/runwpa
file:///home/big_bob/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/wlan0dhcp
```

These are the files i downloaded, the top 5 are Dir, how do i install these in Ubuntu 20

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 (different product to the more common 20.04; as *year* format is used for *snap* only products of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

It is quite often the case that the manufacturer provided driver files are outdated and won’t successfully compile on newer kernel versions. However, let’s try and find out. Please open a terminal and,with a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
cd ~/Downloads/tp/TL-WN781ND_EU_V3_180409_linux/
make
sudo make install
```

If there are errors, post them as well as the result of:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```